# Services menu launches wrong application bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, service

I have implemented a MacOS Service based on the 'simpleEncrypt' example from the Apple documentation.  I'm running 10.9 and Xcode 6.2.

I can build the application bundle, copy it to /Applications, run it once, and my service will appear in other applications' Services menu as expected.

If I run 'pbs -dump_pboard', the correct path to my application bundle appears as NSBundlePath, as expected.

However, when I select my service from a Services menu, MacOS will launch an old copy of my application that resides in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives.

If I delete that old copy, it will run another copy from someplace else.  Only after I delete every other application bundle on the filesystem that has the same CFBundleName as my service's NSPortName will MacOS launch the right one from /Applications.  And when it does, the service works properly.

How can I get MacOS to reliably invoke the correct application bundle for my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OS X, applications are registered with [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html), which is responsible for executing an application when requested, either by double-clicking on its app bundle, via spotlight, or in your case, running from the Services menu.

Registration is automatic and happens, for example, when an application is copied to the /Applications folder (which does more than just copy the files) or even by just running the process.

The list of registered applications can be viewed by running the `lsregister` command with the `-dump` argument. On OS X 10.10, it would be this: -

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
```

As you have multiple copies of the same application, their registration details are identical, so Launch Services will not update its database and simply executes the first seen application matching the registration details.

In the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD), it suggests that you can either register the application in code with the functions `LSRegisterFSRef` and `LSRegisterURL`, using the `inUpdate` boolean parameter, or alternatively:

> update the modification time of the application to ensure that it will be updated by the automatic registration utilities

I expect you'll still have to run the application directly, to ensure Launch Services updates its database. In the case of a bundle, you can navigate directly to the application's binary. Using Caculator.app as an example you'd execute:-

```
/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

Another option I've found is to update the application's Info.plist by incrementing the version number, or more radically, changing its CFBundleIdentifier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In my case, copying the .app bundle to /Applications and/or running it would cause the system to re-read its .plist (as expected) which was confirmed by the updated NSMenuItem string in the Services menu.  However, when the menu item was selected, it attempted to run a copy of the service itself from another location.  And as I mentioned, 'pbs -dump_pboard' showed the right NSBundlePath for the service.  However, if I ran 'lsregister -kill' followed by 'lsregister -seed -dump', the database seemed to get rebuilt sensibly, and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it's running the service from a different location; the one in which it was first registered. Using the `lsregister -kill` resets the Launch Service database and the `lsregister -seed` rescans and registers found applications. However, it still stands that having multiple versions of the same application can get confusing, but at least you now know why.

Comment: Done. It still feels like a bug that Launch Services should only partially update its database when it encounters a new bundle, and when a Service bundle cannot be found, that it should give priority to ones it discovers in nonstandard places instead of the one it already knows about in /Applications.

Comment: If the bundle is 'new', it should have a higher version number in its Info.plist. It just doesn't consider modification or creation time when comparing.